# git modify codes of a tag, and keep commits info after this tag

Tags: git

My git repo is like this:

cm1.. cm10, tag A, cm11, cm12. ....cm 20

code running at tag A,

cm11...cm20 are new futures.

But now, tag A here has a bug, I need fixed it,

How do I modify code, and merge in tag A,

I know, I can `reset --soft A`, then modify some file, add them, then commit.

but after this, cm11...cm20 changes are still here, But I lost this commits information.

So, how can i modify a tag, and keep the commits info after this tag?

Comment: As you mentioned, there are ways to cheat but these circumvent the intent that tags are not to be changed.  Personally, I'd start a branch from A to represent your current production code.

Comment: Agreed with @Arthur Dent . "code running at tag A" There is major difference between tags and branches. There is nothing running at tag but at branch.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to *insert* a commit at `tag A` to fix some bug but let the commit history stay linear.

Suppose you are on `cm20`.

```
git branch feature
git checkout tagA

...fix something and commit...

git commit -m 'bug fix'
git rebase HEAD feature
```

then you have a bug-fixed branch `feature` which has a clean commit log history as you want.

I recommend keeping `feature` as a development branch because you noted **cm11..cm20 are new futures**, but in this case it is in fact a temporary branch and can be removed later.

Comment: thx, this is maybe what i want. I haven't using rebase command, I should test it and be understand first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `rebase` is some degree a 'dangerous' command especially you have shared the branch with others. Here I create a new branch 'feature', it should not break existing branches though.

Comment: I think `git rebase` suggested here could cause conflict if there's a change after `tag A` that conflicts against the change made at tag A.